# how to align left and right in border

Tags: flutter

```
Positioned(
                    left: 16,
                    right: 16,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 66,
                    child: response.users.photo != null
                        ? Image.network(Modal.url + response.users.photo, width: 120, height: 140,)
                        : Image.asset(
                            'assets/user-icon.png',
                          ),
                    ),
```

i have a problem, i want image align right and left in the border, please help me!
[image]

Comment: is my solution working? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ClipOval to draw image inside `CircleAvatar`

```dart
     ClipOval(
              child: new CircleAvatar(
                radius: 66,
                child: new Image.asset('assets/images/image.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle both case (with and without image) and avoid radius is to use `ClipOval` and `CircleAvatar` with proper params.

## How to use it

In place where you are using it, you can put:

```
child: Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  child: ClipOval(
    child: buildAvatar(photo),
  ),
),
```

and this is only one place where you are setting dimentions (no `radius` etc.).

## Build avatar

And this method will return two types of `Widget` base on photo (is it null or not)

```
Widget buildAvatar(String photo) {
  if (photo == null) {
    return CircleAvatar(
        child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/user-icon.png',
      ),
    ));
  } else {}
  return CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
      photo,
    ),
  );
}
```

## Demo

In runtime I modify photo (is it `null` or `url`) ans size (`150x150` and `300x300`)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to add fit cover is in Image.

This is example:

```dart
ClipOval(
      child: Image.asset(
        path_image,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ))
```

OR

or

```dart
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30.0,
                backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage('your_img_url'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey, // placeholder color 
              )

``

I hope this helps
```